# What is meant by outside of hive?

Tags: hive, hdfs

I read that while using external tables data is stored outside of HIVE.
what does it mean by outside? 
Is that something like outside of HDFS ?
Can one please explain me in terms of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration, `hive-site.xml` has the `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property, with a value such as `/usr/hive/warehouse`. When you don't specify an alternative storage location, Hive places table data under this HDFS directory.

Note that you can set a custom `LOCATION` for both External tables and regular tables, in order to store the data 'outside of Hive'. This is typically still an HDFS location. The difference with External tables is that when you drop the table, the data is not deleted from HDFS, since it is assumed that data belongs to some other application.